# Excel convert string to number when open CSV file

Tags: excel, csv

In some cases Excel convert CSV file string into number.
How do I stop it?
Example

```
a,b,c
8,"3,54,4",4
22,"34,543,40",55
4,"5,401,5404",32
```

[image]

The last string `"5,401,5404"` will appear like a number in Excel

[image]

How can I fix it without changing the source file?
I know some workarounds like using Python or adding spaces to the string ("5, 401, 5404"), but I am looking for a way to solve it using the Excel itself.

Comment: What is your version of Excel?

Comment: You can **import** the file instead of **open**ing the file. The wizard will allow you to designate those columns as **text** and the format will be preserved. If you use `Power Query` (aka `Data=>Get & Transform=>From Text/CSV`), you will be able to save the query and reuse it if your csv file changes.

Answer (score 1):

In excel,  file..options...advanced

Temporarily change the **systems separator ... thousands separator...** to something else besides a comma

[image]

Comment: Nice, but not helping me. I'm looking for smoothing like "import string as sting"

Comment: That will let you import "1,000,000" as a string instead of a number, but ok

Comment: There is one option under -->`File` --> `Excel Options` --> `Data` --> `Automatic Data Conversion` --> Uncheck all enabled ones, it will keep as `Strings` probably its in Beta Version. Look **[here](https://imgur.com/gallery/JYB7HtP)** I hope it will work